# Comparing String with object

Tags: java

I have an `addUser()` method that adds a new user to the `<FacebookUser>` users ArrayList.

```
void addUser() {
    String username;
    String password;
    String passwordHint;

    System.out.println("Please type in your desired username:");
    username = input.nextLine();
    if (users.toString().contains(username)) {
        System.out.println("Username already exists!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please type in your desired password:");
        password = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please type in your password hint:");
        passwordHint = input.nextLine();
        FacebookUser newUser = new FacebookUser(username, password);
        newUser.setPasswordHint(passwordHint);
        users.add(newUser);
    }

}
```

I'm now trying to make a `deleteUser()` method and I got stuck at this part. I'm supposed to compare the given password with the the Facebook User's password that is associated with the given username. If the passwords match, I should remove the `FacebookUser` object from the users ArrayList.

```
void deleteUser() {
    String username;
    String password;

    System.out.println("Please type in your username:");
    username = input.nextLine();
    if (users.toString().contains(username)) {
        System.out.println("Please type in your password:");
        password = input.nextLine();


    } else {
        System.out.println("Username doesn't exist!");
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which part of the problem is problematic to you?

Comment: what is users in `users.toString()` where is it defined.?

Comment: Comparing the given password to the password associated with the object  associated with the given username. Basically finding out if the passwords are equal or not.

Comment: @shishi There are too many codes you should show, but is not being shown. You have to show us the variables in your User class and the ArrayList you use to store the list of users.

Comment: users is an ArrayList
ArrayList<FacebookUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Where is users being stored and is there a primary key to identify all users? Is username unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm supposed to compare the given password with the Facebook User's password that is associated with the given username.

Keeping my solution simple. Your first step is get the targeted user object from the list.

```
User target = null;
for(User u : users)
    if(u.getUserName().equals(enteredUserName))  //Assuming all usernames are unique
        target = u;
```

Next, check whether given password matches.

```
if(target.getPassword().equals(enteredPassword)) //if password matches
    users.remove(target);    //delete user from list
```

Comment: **Remarks:** You may override the equals method and hashcode, but this looks like school work to me. Usually institution does not require you to do that. They want to test whether you know how to search through a list and get the targeted object. So given here is a solution which will most probably be expected by schools.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked 100% for me. I'm still new to asking questions here, so sorry for not phrasing the question properly. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume `users` is a `List`.

Here's a good `method` to do it if the `getters` are correct.

You just find the right index of `username` and then check the password.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < users.length() ; i++){
    if (users.get(i).getName().equals(username)){
        if (users.get(i).getPassword().equals(password)) System.out.println("Deleted");
        else System.out.println("Password incorrect !");
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT : Here I just printed out the actions to be crystal clear but in practice, the best is to store the index and delete the index once you've breaken out the loop

Comment: You're welcome @shishi . Here's a helpful link : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   Have a nice evening and a good night